# Ansible: rerun playbook from failed task

Tags: ansible

I am executing play-book on only one host.

My Current task execution flow is:
1) Executing task
2) If any of the task fails in between, clean up everything
3) Rerun from the beginning.

This does not sound very efficient. I want to create flow very much like this,

1) Executing task
2) Task failed ..
3) if we rerun the play-book, ansible should execute tasks from the failed task. It should not rerun from the beginning.

In attempt to do that I was trying to achieve that once task was failed, I was trying to execute play-book with "--limit", it throws following error.

```
root@centos:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook stack.yml --limit -vvvv
ERROR: provided hosts list is empty

root@centos:/etc/ansible# cat /root/stack.retry
10.17.10.150
```

I am not sure is this the right way to rerun the play-book to achieve this work flow.

Comment: You should really be making your playbooks idempotent. If they are idempotent, then the only issue with re-running from the beginning is time.

Comment: I am trying to build idempotent playbook, Most of the places i am using 'shell' and 'command' module in playbook so make it idempotent i am taking help of "creates" argument.

The issue you mentioned is remains always .. another issue i am facing is.. 
Once task is executed and if task is failed, output of task will be logged in the file and in the next run of the palybook, ansible is skipping the successfully executed tasks and the failed tasks as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option --start-at-task=START_AT

This will start your playbook at the task matching the given name. In your case:

```
ansible-playbook stack.yml --start-at-task=START_AT
```

change "START_AT" with the name of the task you will start at.

The --limit option you have used is to limit the playbook to hosts matching the pattern and not limiting tasks

Comment: `--start-at-task` does not work for tasks defined within roles

Comment: `--start-at-task` does not resume with state of the playbook that failed.

Comment: `--start-at-task` does not reproduce the initial state with all required variables which are expected to have been registered by preceding tasks